# Why does 0 && a Boolean evaluate to 0 instead of the Boolean?

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression, boolean-expression

Why does 0 && and a Boolean evaluate to a 0 instead of the Boolean?

> 0 && false
>   > 0
>   0 && true
>   > 0

But false && 0 returns false and true && 0 returns true

> false && 0
>   > false

I thought a numeric value and a false expression would return a Boolean always.

> 1 && false
>   > false

Comment: because 0 is falsey, so the `&& ....` is never evaluated ... because Boolean logic - perhaps you're thinking of bitwise operators like `&` instead of Boolean `&&`

Comment: `true && 0` doesn't return `true`; it returns `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators):

> the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value

and

> `expr1 && expr2`: Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.

Since `0` can be converted to false, and `0` is `expr1`, it returns `0`.